# Nativescript - hide the navigation bar (iOS)

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to hide the navigation bar in iOS (NS 2.5)

`

```
<Page.actionBar>
  <ActionBar class="action-bar" title="About">
      <ios>
        <NavigationButton visibility="collapse"/>
        <ActionBar.actionItems>
          <ActionItem tap="onBackTap" ios.position="left" text="< Back"/>
        </ActionBar.actionItems>
      </ios>
  </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>`
```

But I still get the default '<' from the nav-bttn.

Comment: I think it would be `visibility="collapsed"`, with a d on the end. Not sure if it'll make it actually disappear though.

Answer (score 0):

`<NavigationButton visibility="collapse"/>` it's supposed to be collapsed.

Solution: `<NavigationButton visibility="collapsed"/>`

Comment: like so: <NavigationButton visibility="collapsed"/>